# everything is correct but cant run :error expected { or ;

Tags: c++, class

i cant find where is my error can  u please help me ? the error is expected ; or } but i already put it there i cant run it though.do u  know  why? the drived class is  closed by ; although still the program can not compile . please guide me thanks

```
  #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class myBase{
          private:
                  int foodmoney;
                  int hobbymoney;

                  public:
               void setdata();
          friend int caldata();
                 };
                 void myBase::setdata(){
                      cout<<"Enter foodmoney :" ;cin>>foodmoney;
                      cout<<"enter hoobymoney:";cin>>hobbymoney;
                      }
              int caldata(int sum,int foodmoney,int hobbymoney){
                        cin>>foodmoney;
                        cin>>hobbymoney;          
                        sum=(foodmoney+hobbymoney)/2;
                        return sum;

                             }


        class Derivedclass:public myBase{
                        int moneyforfood,moneyforhobby;
                        public:
               int setmydrived(int moneyforfood,int moneyforhobby){
                        cout<<"enter money for food(drived class)"<<endl;
                        cin>>moneyforfood;
                        cout<<"enter money for hobby(drived class)"<<endl;
                        cin>>moneyforhobby;
                        }

                        int calculatedrived(){

                   int sumd=(moneyforfood+moneyforhobby);
                     cout<<"avg money on frived class "<<sumd<<endl;
                     };


                    int main(){
                     myBase baseobj;
                     baseobj.setdata();
                     int caldata();
          Derivedclass obj;
                     int setmydrived();
                     obj.calculatedrived();
                      system("puase");

         }
```

Comment: fixing indentation would tell you that **not everything** is alright

Comment: Starting a question with `everything is correct` doesn't make any seance...

Comment: @user2203809 Indent your code properly! What you have now is ridiculous. Check this link for some ideas: [Indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)

Answer (score 4):

You're missing closing brace (and the semicolon) for the last class' definition.

That kind of thing is easier to spot if you use a sane indentation style.

You're also missing two return statements in functions that return something. That's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `;` after class declarations. Example:

```
class Whatever {

};
```

Comment: OP did add semicolons at least on the spots I notice. If there was sane indentation this would be easier to check of course.

Answer (score 0):

There were few errors in your code:

- You were missing a closing braces (`}`) for `class Derivedclass:public myBase`
- The spelling of pause was incorrect in system("pause")
- The `int setmydrived` and `int calculatedrived` functions should return an integer, but you were not returning an integer.

I have corrected the bugs. The following code will work fine (see demonstration on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/cNn5wu)):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myBase
{
private:
    int foodmoney;
    int hobbymoney;

public:
    void setdata();
    friend int caldata();
};
void myBase::setdata()
{
    cout<<"Enter foodmoney :" ;cin>>foodmoney;
    cout<<"enter hoobymoney:";cin>>hobbymoney;
}
int caldata(int sum,int foodmoney,int hobbymoney)
{
    cin>>foodmoney;
    cin>>hobbymoney;          
    sum=(foodmoney+hobbymoney)/2;
    return sum;

}


class Derivedclass:public myBase
{
    int moneyforfood,moneyforhobby;
public:
    int setmydrived(int moneyforfood,int moneyforhobby)
    {
        cout<<"enter money for food(drived class)"<<endl;
        cin>>moneyforfood;
        cout<<"enter money for hobby(drived class)"<<endl;
        cin>>moneyforhobby;
                    /*THIS FUNCTION DOESNOT RETURN ANY INT VAL*/
    }

    int calculatedrived()
    {

        int sumd=(moneyforfood+moneyforhobby);
        cout<<"avg money on frived class "<<sumd<<endl;
        //return sumd;
                    /*THIS FUNCTION DOESNOT RETURN ANY INT VAL*/

    }
};

int main()
{
    myBase baseobj;
    baseobj.setdata();
    int caldata();
    Derivedclass obj;
    int setmydrived();
    obj.calculatedrived();
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: I downvoted because when this answer was posted, it contained only a block of code. No explanation for what the problem was and therefore was not an answer to the question. I see that you've since edited the answer to add an explanation, but that wasn't there when it was first posted and when I saw it. If you with to avoid downvotes in the future, don't click the "Submit" button until you have a complete answer. [downvote removed]

Comment: @CodyGray: Thank you! Yeah correct, it deserve Downvote as initially i  just fixed the poor indentation , fixed the compilation error and posted the running code without explanation.
Then i wrote explanation as an edit.Actually, not quite experienced here at S.O., so sometime i make these sort of mistake. Thank-you once again. :)